# Making 50% of a value be the max value of another variable (and 0%/100% equal to minimum value)

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, percentage

I'm making a game using Unity Engine and I want a sun object to increase in brightness until it reaches a specific time of day and then start decreasing after that time.

I have the day-time represented as a percentage value (0 to 1) of daylight hours like so:

```
float currentTime = 0.50f; //50% = noon, 0%/100% = midnight
float dayRange = 0.75f - 0.25f; //Daylight hours = 25% to 75% (6:00 to 18:00)
float dayPercent = (currentTime - 0.25f) / dayRange; //Current time between the daylight hours as a percentage.
float maxSunLight = 10f;
float currentSunLight = 5f;
```

What I want:

When `dayPercent` is between 0 and 0.5, `currentSunLight` will increase from 0 to 10.

When `dayPercent` is between 0.5 and 1, `currentSunLight` will decrease from 10 to 0.

I have a messy way of doing this, but I'm sure there's likely a simple math function for this?

Edit: Just to include my "messy" way

```
if(dayPercent <= 0.50f){
    currentSunLight =  (dayPercent * 2) / maxSunLight * 100;
} else {
    currentSunLight = (dayPercent / 2) / maxSunLight * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest something like this, sticking to your current logic:

```cs
currentSunLight = 10 - Math.Abs(dayPercent - 0.5) * 20;
```

But this is a linear approach, that means, your sun "rises" linearly and then suddenly sets linearly again, as if it was moving in a triangle. A better way to calculate this is using trigonometric functions to achieve a more realistic scene:

```cs
currentSunLight = Math.Cos( dayPercent * Math.PI ) * 10;
```